# When calling NAIF SPICE subroutines in Fortran-95 I recieve Segmentation fault Invalid memory reference

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, subroutine

I'm trying to use naif spice toolkit for Fortran.
I downloaded from here https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit.html the version for PC, Linux, gfortran, 64bit.
I wrote a primitive program which does nothing but writing to the screen 'I call furnsh' and calling furnsh. I add the whole code:

```
program testfur  
    implicit none  
    character(len = 100) :: kernelfile = '/home/path_to_spice/Kernels/ck/10328_11017py_as_flown.bc'  
    
    write(*,*) kernelfile  
    call FURNSH(kernelfile)  
    write(*,*) 'loaded kernels'  

end
```

The description of the subroutine I call here can be found at
https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/FORTRAN/spicelib/furnsh.html

However, the other subroutines from this toolkit behave in the same way, so I believe the problem is more general.
I compile my program linking it to "spicelib.a" like this
gfortran -g -fcheck=all *.f95 /home/path_to_spice/toolkit/lib/spicelib.a
When I run the program, a segmentation fault happens when a spice subroutine is called. I tried it for "FURNSH" and "str2et." The segmentation fault happens before the subroutines start executing, otherwise I would see a more detailed complaint from the routines themselves.

The program prints '/home/path_to_spice/Kernels/ck/10328_11017py_as_flown.bc' and then immediately this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
Backtrace for this error:  
#0  0x7fd763a1cbd0 in ???  
#1  0x7fd763a1be25 in ???  
#2  0x7fd76372fd5f in ???  
#3  0x7fd763a1c2f0 in ???  
#4  0x7fd763c595d5 in ???  
#5  0x7fd763c46a2c in ???  
#6  0x562bb2e0379e in ???  
#7  0x562bb2dd88b3 in ???  
#8  0x562bb2dbabb4 in ???  
#9  0x562bb2dba78e in ???  
#10  0x562bb2dba3a4 in testfur  
    at /home/veyza/furnsh_test/test_furnsh.f95:6  
#11  0x562bb2dba44b in main
    at /home/veyza/furnsh_test/test_furnsh.f95:9  
Segmentation fault
```

What can be the reason?
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: The reason, almost certainly, is a bug in your code or the library you are using. Without seeing any code all I can suggest is compiling with `gfortran -g -fcheck=all *.f95 /home/path_to_spice/toolkit/lib/spicelib.a`, then run it and see what happens. But really to have any chance of an answer we will need a *complete*, compilable, minimal, reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, I compiled with -g -fcheck=all and got these two lines that are different from the usual.  

#10  0x555eebb863a4 in testfur
 at /home/veyza/furnsh_test/test_furnsh.f95:6  

#11  0x555eebb8644b in main
 at /home/veyza/furnsh_test/test_furnsh.f95:9

Comment: Please edit the question to include these lines, *and* also a couple of lines above them. This may tell you where and maybe a few details about what the bug is, but without code we can't help you further.

Comment: Looks like we need also the information from the FURNSH subroutine and its calling seqiuence.